# How to hide Selenium ChromeDriver console in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to convert these C# code to VB .NET? I just can't figured out.

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
```

or

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-web-security", "--disable-gpu", "--incognito", "--proxy-bypass-list=*", "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--log-level=3", "--hide-scrollbars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

I just want to hide window console while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the conversions as produced by Telerik's [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/):

```
Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
Dim driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, New ChromeOptions())
```

...and

```
Dim chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
Dim [option] = New ChromeOptions()
[option].AddArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-web-security", "--disable-gpu", "--incognito", "--proxy-bypass-list=*", "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--log-level=3", "--hide-scrollbars")
driver = New ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options)
```

**--EDIT--**

Here's the corrected code from your full sample:

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Keys
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
  Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
    driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, New ChromeOptions())
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    btnStop.Text = "Stopping service..."
    btnStop.Enabled = False
    driver.Quit()
    driver.Dispose()
    btnStop.Text = "Done."
  End Sub

  Private driverService As ChromeDriverService
  Private driver As IWebDriver
End Class
```

Note that `driver` and `driverService` are `Fields` on the class. For more info on class fields, see the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/#fields-and-properties):

> **Fields and properties**
>
> Fields and properties represent information stored in an object. You retrieve and set their values with assignment statements the same way you retrieve and set  local variables in a procedure. The following example retrieves the Width property and sets the ForeColor property of a Label object.
>
> ```
> Dim warningWidth As Integer = warningLabel.Width
> warningLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
> ```

When you want to execute code against an `Object`'s `Property`, such as setting `driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow` to `True`, that action must occur somewhere within a `Method`, `Function` or `Property Accessor`. In this case, that particular line of code is running within the form's constructor, which is a `Method`.

Those sections of the Microsoft documentation will be very good reads for you, when you get a chance.

Comment: Are you placing this code inside a method? If not, you should. It won't work any other way.